# How can solve OAuthException while i am post a message on facebook

Tags: android

i am doing a sample Facebook application in that i am POST a file to a particular person only, while i am doing this i got an error message like..

```
05-27 14:33:51.806: DEBUG/Response(2211): {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: friends"}}
```

**Code:**

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
accesstoken = facebook.getAccessToken();
b.putString("method", "read_stream");
b.putString("attachment","{\"name\":\"" + "\",\"href\":\"google.co.in"; + "\",\"description\":\"" + "\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"" + "" + "\",\"href\":\"" + "\"}]}"); 
String response = facebook.request("friend_id", b, "POST");
```

Comment: If you be more spesific maybe experts can help. For example, what is your code?

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle(); accesstoken = facebook.getAccessToken();
b.putString("method", "read_stream");
b.putString("attachment","{\"name\":\"" + "\",\"href\":\"http://www.google.co.in"
         + "\",\"description\":\""
         + "\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""
         + ""
         + "\",\"href\":\""
         + "\"}]}");
String response = facebook.request("friend_id", b, "POST");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to check documentation for facebook and obtain knowledge, that "friends" is wrong, you should use "friend" or "friendlist" instead.

Comment: I get my friends list and stored in a array list,then i bundled it,the key value is friend_id,,,,may i use that key for post the message

Comment: which method are you using for post?

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle(); accesstoken = facebook.getAccessToken();
b.putString("method", "read_stream");
b.putString("attachment","{\"name\":\"" + "\",\"href\":\"http://www.google.co.in"
         + "\",\"description\":\""
         + "\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""
         + ""
         + "\",\"href\":\""
         + "\"}]}");
String response = facebook.request("friend_id", b, "POST");

Comment: Hmm.. I've looked through Facebook docs and found that "read_stream" is a permission, not method. It seems that your code is complete mess.

Comment: if any possibility for post a message on particular person..not a wall

Comment: Do you mean post to someones wall, or send private message?

Comment: First, make sure you have enough permissions, and you need use this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/